# Default Index Controller Not Being Called With New Zend Studio Project

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

I have just purchased a license for Zend Studio 9.  I have only a minimal amount of experience with the Zend framework, and no previous experience with Zend Studio.  I am using http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/ as a tutorial on the framework and have browsed through the resources located at http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/resources for help with the studio software.

My main problem is that after creating a new Zend project with zstudio, I'm not seeing the initial welcome message.  Here are the steps I am using:

1. I've already installed the Zend Server and confirmed that web apps are working (made some test files, they all parsed correctly).
2. Create a new project with Zend Studio.
   a.  File->New->Local PHP Project
   b.  For location, I am using C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs.
   c.  For version I used the default "Zend Framework 1.11.11 (Built-in)"
3. I go to http://localhost:81/projectname.  Instead of the default index controller being called, I just see my directory structure.

Addition info:
OS:  Windows 7
PHP version:  5.3

ERROR LOGS:

```
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:30 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:30 2011] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:30 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:30 2011] [notice] Digest: done
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:31 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:31 2011] [notice] Server built: Aug  8 2010 16:45:53
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:31 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 13788
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:32 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:32 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:32 2011] [notice] Digest: done
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:33 2011] [notice] Child 13788: Child process is running
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:33 2011] [notice] Child 13788: Acquired the start mutex.
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:33 2011] [notice] Child 13788: Starting 64 worker threads.
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:33 2011] [notice] Child 13788: Starting thread to listen on port 10081.
>[Wed Nov 30 14:32:33 2011] [notice] Child 13788: Starting thread to listen on port 81.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to http://localhost:81/projectname/index/index does the correct screen load?

If so:

- Check that the .htaccess file in your public directory contains the correct rewrite rules for Zend Framework.
- Check your httpd.conf file and make sure index.php is added to the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

I think the solution is going to be the second bullet, but let me know what you find and I can help further if that doesn't work.  Make sure to restart apache after you make any changes to httpd.conf.

Otherwise, report any errors you see when you access the controller directly, and check Apache's `error_log` file to see if you get any errors.

Comment: That file doesn't exist.  Here's what my directory structure looks like:  
#  .buildpath
# .project
# .settings/
# .zfproject.xml
# application/
# docs/
# library/
# public/
# tests/

I added the <Directory> directive to my localhost, but after doing that apache wouldn't restart.

Comment: So `public/.htaccess` doesn't exist?  This is part of your problem then.  You don't need to add a <Directory> directive to httpd.conf, just make sure that `<DirectoryIndex>` contains index.php.  By default it contains only index.html